# Проблемы с именем пакета

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package

Здравствуйте.При создании проекта должен получить пакет
`com.my.program` а получаю `myprogramname.program.my.com`.Не пойму может что тыкнул. Как вернуться к нормальному виду пакета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании проекта в Android Studio, Вы вводите Application name и Company domain, исходя их которых генерируется Package name.

Для того, чтобы получить пакет `com.my.program` нужно вводить Company domain `program.my.com`.

Comment: Раньше вводил все как написал, а тут понадобилось переименовать пакет и смотрю там дебри стали.

Comment: Что то не помню что бы что то в android studio обнавлял.Теперь нужно при создании проекта из Package Name удалить имя приложения.Наделали.

Comment: А при установки программы пакет все равно задом наперед становится